# Алгоритм заполнения пустыми значениями суточного расписания

Tags: php

Имеется массив вида:

```
[2018-01-10] => Array
    (
        [11:00-12:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test1'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 1'
            )

        [18:00-19:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 2'
            )

        [19:00-21:30] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 1'
            )

    )
```

Дата. И внутри вложенные массивы с занятым в указанную дату временем. Нужно на выходе получить массив такой же структуры, но с записями о пустом времени. Т.е. следующего вида:

```
[2018-01-10] => Array
    (
        [00:00-11:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )

        [11:00-12:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test1'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 1'
            )

        [12:00-18:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )

        [18:00-19:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 2'
            )

        [19:00-21:30] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 1'
            )

        [21:30-23:59] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )
    )
```

Как правильно подойти к решению задачи? Как быть? Вычитать интервалы один от другого, писать кучу условий? Или как?

```
$start_time=strtotime('00:00');
$end_time=strtotime('23:59');
    foreach ($occupancy as $date => $data) {
        foreach ($data as  $time => $value) {
            $current_interval=explode('-', $time);
            $current_start=strtotime($current_interval[0]);
            $current_end=strtotime($current_interval[1]);

            //???
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Вычитать интервалы один от другого, писать кучу условий?* Вычитать - зачем? Куча условий - зачем? отсортировать исходный массив по возрастанию времени начала, проверить на отсутствие пересечений, а затем добавлять интервалы от конца предыдущего до начала следующего, проверяя, что они ненулевой длины, и добавив два псевдоэлемента - один со временем окончания 0:00, и второй со временем начала 24:00. Ещё проще - сразу добавить псевдоэлементы нулевой длины, безусловно добавить промежуточные, а потом в один проход вычистить все нулевые, включая псевдоэлементы.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что значит "псевдоэлементы", "безусловно добавить промежуточные"

Comment: Я когда-то наткнулся на класс работающий с интервалами, посмотрите там по ссылке, Там где-то есть., Мне с телефона неудобно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850490/split-a-date-array-into-available-shifts-to-work

Comment: @Akina не могли бы вы более подробно уточнить? Так, например, я наткнулся на вот такой класс - https://gist.github.com/hakre/6859a19fa9108ba0173d Но вы говорите, что можно решить как-то проще. Поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

> не могли бы вы более подробно уточнить?

Не тянет на ответ, но не помещается в комментарий. Схематично:

```
    // сортируем по возрастанию времени начала
Array = Sort(Array by start_time ASC)
    // добавляем псевдозапись свободного интервала в начало
Array.Add([00:00-00:00] before first)
    // добавляем псевдозапись свободного интервала в конец
Array.Add([24:00-24:00] after last)
    // Между каждой парой элементов вставляем свободный интервал
for i = Array.Length downto 1
  { Array.Add([Array(i-1).end_time-Array(i).start_time] before Array(i)) }
    // Удаляем все интервалы нулевой длины 
for i = Array.Length downto 0
  { If Array(i).start_time = Array(i).end_time { Array.Remove(i) } }\
```

Обратный перебор используется для того, чтобы не возиться с пересчётом текущего индекса при добавлении/удалении элементов.

Answer (score 1):

У вас очень неудачная структура хранения данных. Если её можно поменять, то я бы сделал как-то так:

```
[2018-01-10] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [start] => 600   // в минутах от 00:00
                [end] => 660
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [start] => 660   
                [end] => 720
                [direction] => 'Test1'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'Группа 1'
            )
```

Тогда задача решается элементарно:

```
function makeEmpty($start, $end){
    return ['start' => $start, 
        'end' => $end,
        'direction' => null,
        'color' => 'success',
        'group' => null
       ]
}

$in = [исходный массив];
$out = [];

usort($in, function ($a, $b){return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;});

if($in[0]['start'] > 0) $out[] = makeEmpty(0, $in[0]['start']);

$last = null;
foreach($in as $current){
    if($last !== null){
        if($current['start'] > $last['end']) $out[] = makeEmpty($last['end'], $current['start']);
    }
    $out[] = $current;
    $last = $current;
}

if($last['end'] < 24) $out[] = makeEmpty($last['end'], 24);
```